# Do Visual Studio unit tests in a batch run only do static initialization once?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Do Visual Studio unit tests in a batch run only do static initialization once?

This seems to be so. I have for example a static object with cached information in a class. I use this class in two unit tests. If I run them separately they run okay. If I run them together, I have to explicitly clear the cache again.

So it seems when I run 'Test1' and 'Test2', the static information from 'Test1' is preserved when I start to run 'Test2'.

I am presently rewriting my test, but is there anything I can to about that, in an option? By the way the static information is not part of my test itself of course, but part of the module I have to run the test on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static is .. static.

Variables (and constructors) of such are *not* automatically "reset" unless a new [Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs(v=vs.110).aspx) (or .NET process) is used for each test, which is not the case.

The solution is to not use static (or really any) state in unit tests not Setup or contained entirely within the test itself.

Comment: Thank you. The static cache is not from the unit test, but from the class I have to test. I am now explicitly clearing this static information before running each test. Thanks for confirming my thoughts and to inform me there is not other quick solution for this.

Comment: @JaJa I use (and recommend) using DI/IoC and *eliminating* static data and methods wherever possible. Doing so makes it much more easy to deal with cases like this.

Comment: Thank you. I have found some information on the connection between DI and Unit testing. The elimination of static data is not possible though, since I have a few singleton classes that I have to write tests for, and they pro definition contain static data.

Comment: @JaJa I've rewritten all my previously-static classes to be injected - this includes collections of utility functions. It's easy to make them one-instance-per-container; then given them the same name as the static type would have so it "feels like a static method" from code. When *also* using interfaces it makes for a much more testable and decoupled code-base. It might not be practical to retrofit old code with such, but with new code based on DI/IoC my recommendation is to *not* use static fields (unless, perhaps, they are read-only) or methods.